# macos Catalina "Cannot connect to app store" popup

Tags: macos, catalina, mac-appstore

I see this general issue has been asked about a number of times, but none of them appear to be exactly the same as in my case.  The problem enters if I try to use a link to Apple One services, such as [one.apple.com](https://one.apple.com).  If I do that, I get the popup below and I don't know what else to be looking for here.  2018 MBP running Catalina (10.15.7).  I've tried every "solution" I can find online.  All other network functionality is normal.

[image: Cannot connect to app store]

No other Apple services seem to be impacted.  Music works fine, iCloud seems fine, In fact the store itself even seems to work fine, I see no problems.

Things I have tried/verified:

1. This is not a general network connectivity problem.
2. Apple's services are running fine.
3. As per [this article](https://appuals.com/cannot-connect-to-the-app-store/), the problem is not with my DNS settings, keychain certificates, or proxy settings, and a reboot changed nothing.
4. As per [this article](https://appletoolbox.com/cannot-connect-to-app-store-on-mac-10-steps-to-fix-it/), the problem is not related to my system time or timezone, not changed by logging out/in, not fixed by clearing cache files, and not related to firewall (disabled).

These seem to be the same "solutions" everyone lists everywhere but none have helped me. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Just saying you tried "every 'solution' you can find online" assumes we are all familiar with those solutions. Please edit your question and add a summary of what you have tried.

Comment: Done and done-er.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation of the verbiage on [the Apple One page's FAQ section](https://www.apple.com/apple-one/) leads me to believe that you need to be running Big Sur 11.1 or later *to subscribe* to Apple One services from a device running macOS:

> Apple One services work across your Apple devices, including iPhone and iPod touch with iOS 14 or later, iPad with iPadOS 14 or later, Apple TV with tvOS 14 or later, and Mac with macOS Big Sur 11.1 or later.

Based on the sentence after that (emphasis mine), you should be able to *use* those subscriptions from within macOS Catalina (10.15.7):

> **If you subscribe through another device**, you can still enjoy Apple One on any version of macOS earlier than macOS Big Sur.

When I attempt to open the [Apple One](https://one.apple.com) landing page on a Mac running Big Sur 11.5.2, it shows the **Do you want to allow this page to open "App Store"?** prompt, and I'm able to click the **Allow** button to get it to show the Apple One subscription prompt within the App Store.

*However, if I'm not logged into the App Store when attempting to open that link, it will give a similar error message to what you're seeing* in Catalina (i.e., "Cannot Connect"). As soon as I login to the App Store with my Apple ID, it shows the Apple One subscription plans.

The odd thing is: when visiting the Apple One landing page on a machine running Catalina 10.15.7, *it isn't even prompting me to open the App Store*, so I'm unsure how you're even getting your machine to offer that option.

Is there any chance that you can subscribe from another device that meets the requirements for OS versions, or update your current system to a more recent version in order to subscribe to Apple One services?

Comment: Aha!!  That makes total sense.  I even had wondered if that could be it but hadn't seen any mention of BigSur being required.  I was eventually able to subscribe to what I wanted from my phone instead.  I'm betting this answer is correct and I'm going to accept it.  Thanks!